# Position JLabel in JPanel with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

The idea is to make a `JLabel` inside a `JPanel` inside a `JFrame`. I want to position the label in the bottom left corner and I want to do it with the `GridBagLayout`. I've played around with the `GridBagConstraints` fields but nothing I've done seems to work. The only thing that kind of worked is altering the padding for the `JLayer`, but half of the times it didn't work as planned.

Here's the code:

```
class Panelz extends JFrame{
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel();

public static void main(String[] args){
    Panelz p = new Panelz();
    p.pack();
    p.setVisible(true);
    p.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public Panelz(){
    Dimension scr = new Dimension(500,500);
    this.setPreferredSize(scr);
    Container cont = this.getContentPane();
    cont.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    label.setText("Potato");
    //make panel
    panel.setBackground(Color.red);
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=0;
    c.weighty=100f;

    panel.add(label,c);

    c.weightx=0.2f;
    c.weighty=0.2f;
    cont.add(panel, c);
}
}
```

The output always is the label text in the center of the panel.

Comment: *"I want to have a bunch of JPanels that contain a bunch of JLabels."* Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to position the label in the bottom left corner

```
c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

But you are using fill with a value of "BOTH" which seems. like you are trying to have the label fill the entire panel, not just the bottom left.

```
panel.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Don't set the color of the panel. Instead set the color of the label. Then you will be able to see exactly how the label is being sized by the layout manager. Something like:

```
label.setText("Potato");
label.setOpaque(true);
label.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

Also, there is no need to set the layout of the content pane of the frame.

For a better understanding of how GridBagLayout works read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The working example in the tutorial shows how to display a component at the `bottom right` of a panel. You should be able to modify that code to display the component at the `bottom left` after reading about how the constraints work.

Comment: I'm setting a layout for the content pane because I want to have a bunch of JPanels that contain a bunch of JLabels. I've tried what you suggested and I can see the label, but I still can't move it around. I tried changing the weight values, the bounds and the anchor, but nothing works out.

Comment: Well I can move button 5 anywhere by playing with the anchor constraint. I deleted all the other buttons and then changed the other constraints to make sense for a single component. Get that working first. Then once you understand the basics you move on to a more complex layout with multiple components. Or another option is to keep the BorderLayout. Then you add the label to the Border.Layout.PAGE_END. Then you create another panel which contains your nested panels and add this panel to the CENTER. You are never forced to use a single layout manager.

Comment: `I want to have a bunch of JPanels that contain a bunch of JLabels` - so how is that different than the demo code? First you learn how to position button 5 where you want. Once you understand that basic concept then you can replace the other "buttons" with "panels" each containing a label. Once that works, you add more labels to the first panel and get that to work. Tale slow steps. and make small changes.